# Print of HTML table drops cells in first column

Tags: html, printing

I have identified a strange problem in Internet Explorer and Chrome:  I have a simple HTML table with no layout CSS, 2 columns, no styles, and width set to 100%.  When I attempt to print this table in Internet Explorer (all versions) and Chrome, the first cell on the 2nd page and later is dropped.

Snippet of the HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <table  width='100%' cellspacing='0'>  
      <tr><td  align='left'>Date</td><td  align='left'>Order No.</td></tr>  
      <tr><td  align='left'>5/24/2011</td><td  align='left'>287426</td></tr>
      <!-- SNIP :: Many more rows -->
    </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The entire table can be found at:
https://gist.github.com/1000367

The output in the Print Preview on Internet Explorer, for page 2 looks like:

[image: Missing first cell]

I have added the colored lines and circle to highlight that the left cell is missing.

Any ideas?

I've tried adjusting cellpadding and margins on the outside of the table, with no luck.  As suggested, I have also added the following css rules with no effect:

```
   BODY { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting margin & padding on body{} to 0?

Comment: Hey i dont know why your trying this, how its header in Second Page !!!!

Comment: @stefgosselin - I have attempted to set margin and padding on body with a CSS rule.  That does not work either.

Comment: It's not a solution but an observation. The cells are not missing, they seem to be at the bottom of the previous page... Why they are there I don't know... :)

Comment: You're right @Chris - if I use the page margin sliders on the print preview screen, the first cell peeks into the bottom of the previous page.  It almost looks like the page is being formatted on a 0.5 degree angle...

Comment: @Jeff: yeah... its *really* weird... I've been trying all manner of things like removing attribtues in favour of CSS, using thead and tbody and anythign else I can think of. I also notice that at times I get whitespace above that last line of the page. I am coming to the conclusion that the correct answer is that it is just an IE bug. :)

Comment: IMHO - this sounds like a browser bug... a simple table should NOT break in the middle of a cell.  However, Chrome has a similar, poor handling of this formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE has issues printing when the doctype isn't set correctly.  Try adding a doctype at top of the page. In my test adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your sample fixed the issue.

Comment: Gah! That does indeed seem to do the trick (for me at least, hopefully for the OP). It also makes the thead I put in as a test work as well which is a nice added bonus. Good find. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but you may want to investigate a different css file for print media. This is a common practice, but I am not sure exactly off the top of my head what to suggest for your specific issue. Its been a couple of years since I had to do markup for printing in detail.

I use Blueprint CSS for my sites now and it has a separate css file for print. http://www.blueprintcss.org/ Could be you just need a print specific resent like blueprint offers.

Comment: There was a CSS sheet on this table for print formatting.  That yielded a similar result.  I'm attempting some of the CSS rules from blueprintcss now...  will post my findings shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it is because of the 100%. It might be better to set a fixed size link 400px for the table.

Comment: No good...  The fixed size prevents users from choosing any paper size or orientation other than those the developer specified.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  The web page I am trying to fix is not HTML 5, and has the following DOCTYPE...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

... but even changing to HTML 5 ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

... did not help.  I found that a META tag was also causing this problem...

```
<META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

... when I removed this meta tag even with the HTML 4 DOCTYPE it displayed correctly.